# How to find Activity or Fragment that inflates current open layout file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-studio

I want to find Activity that contains button with the specific title in my project. So I open `strings.xml`, search string id, press `Find Usage...` and open layout that contains desired button (`my_layout_1.xml` for example).

The question is: how can I jump to `Activity` or `Fragment` that inflates `my_layout_1.xml` right from the open file tab in Android Studio? Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you have your `.xml` file opened you should see a small icon **C** in the top-left corner of your root layout.

[image]